# Get the current backoff value when using Spring RetryTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry, retrytemplate

So I've been experimenting with Spring's Retry Template.  Everything is working as expected.  One thing I would like however is the ability to extract or log the current backoff time that's being used.  I had a look through the docs/searched everywhere but I can't find any easy way of getting this.

```
    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();

        exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000); // 10 secs
        exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);    // double the backoff
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }
```

And I'm using it like this...

```
retryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
    myService.templateRetryService();
    return null;
});
```

The [RetryCallback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback.html) only provides the RetryConext but this doesn't contain what I need.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: In your case, if you want to track the state, you should not use a `StatelessBackOffPolicy` like `FixedBackOffPolicy`. Maybe something like `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` will give you that control. You can subclass it and assign that to the `retryTemplate` and log stuff in your custom class.

Comment: Thanks, and my apologies but the FixedBackOffPolicy was a copy/paste error.  I've corrected the question now to reflect this.  I am using the ExponentialBackoffPolicy.  Even if I was to subclass this policy however I don't see any way of accessing the internal backOff time.  I would somehow have to maintain and manage my own backOff time which would nullify the benefits of using the spring library in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom `Sleeper` on the `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` to log the time.

```
/**
 * Public setter for the {@link Sleeper} strategy.
 * @param sleeper the sleeper to set defaults to {@link ThreadWaitSleeper}.
 */
public void setSleeper(Sleeper sleeper) {
    this.sleeper = sleeper;
}
```

The default sleeper is this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ThreadWaitSleeper implements Sleeper {

    @Override
    public void sleep(long backOffPeriod) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(backOffPeriod);
    }

}
```

Comment: oh that's exactly what I was looking for, that should work perfectly.  Thanks!